# Usage of "Responsible for having"

Tags: grammar

If some functionality A makes B to do something, can we say

- A is responsible for having B to do sth.
- A is responsible for making B to do sth.

Do both sentences make sense? To me, it seems like the second one is natural but I am wondering whether we can switch "making" to "having" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the word "to" removed, both forms are grammatical, with slightly different meanings. Both "have" and "make" in this causative use take a bare infinitive, without "to" (the `plain form` of the verb):

[Google Books Advanced English Grammar](http://Like%20verbs%20of%20the%20senses,%20verbs%20with%20causative%20meaning%20like%20make%20and%20have%20(verbs%20that%20communicate%20that%20someone%20wants%20someone%20else%20to%20do%20something)%20are%20complemented%20by%20an%20NP%20followed%20by%20a%20bare%20infnitive.%20Get%20can%20also%20have%20causative%20meaning,%20but%20it%20takes%20an%20NP%20followed%20by%20a%20to-infnitive%20compleme)

> Like verbs of the senses, verbs with causative meaning like make and have
> (verbs that communicate that someone wants someone else to do something)
> are complemented by an NP followed by a *bare infinitive*.

1. A is responsible for having B do sth.
2. A is responsible for making B do sth.

The second version sounds more forceful. It might suggest that B didn't want to do sth.